# Return related table data in MVC view

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm creating a golf app to store all my rounds of golf and what I have scored.

I am getting an error with the `RoundViewModel` and the `ScoreViewModel` where I get the following error,

> Error CS1061  'RoundViewModel' does not contain a definition for
>   'Score' and no accessible extension method 'Score' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'RoundViewModel' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

The code for the create.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   //Get database values
   var dbcourse = db.Course.ToList();

   //Make selectlist, which is IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
   var courseNameDropdownList = new SelectList(db.Course.Select(item => new SelectListItem()
   {
       Text = item.CourseName.ToString(),
       Value = item.CourseId.ToString()
   }).ToList(), "Value", "Text");

   // Assign the Selectlist to the View Model  
   var viewCourse = new RoundViewModel()
   {
       Course = dbcourse.FirstOrDefault(),
       // The Dropdownlist values
       CourseNamesDropdownList = courseNameDropdownList,
   };
   return View(viewCourse);
}
```

The code for the RoundViewModel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace GolfScore.Models
{
    public class RoundViewModel
    {
       [Key]
       public int RoundId { get; set; }

       [Display(Name = "Round")]
       public int RoundNumber { get; set; }

       [Display(Name = "Date round played")]
       [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
       public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

       public int? CourseId { get; set; }
       public virtual CourseViewModel Course { get; set; }

       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CourseNamesDropdownList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the code for the ScoreViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GolfScore.Models
{
   public class ScoreViewModel
   {
       [Key]
       public int ScoreId { get; set; }

       [Range(1 , 20)]
       public int ScoreTotal { get; set; }

       public int? HoleId { get; set; }
       public virtual HoleViewModel Hole { get; set; }

       public int? RoundId { get; set; }
       public RoundViewModel Round { get; set; }
   }
}
```

and the code for the create view

```
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Hole</th>
            <th>Par</th>
            <th>Score</th>


        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Course.Holes)
        {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoleNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Par.ParNumber)
        </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Score.ScoreTotal )
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Score.ScoreTotal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Score, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr>
        }

    </table>
</dd>
```

I have tried amending the `RoundViewModel` to include

```
public int? ScoreId { get; set; }
public virtual ScoreViewModel Score { get; set; }
```

but this causes the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'GolfScore.Models.ScoreViewModel' and
>   'GolfScore.Models.RoundViewModel'. The principal end of this
>   association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

Any help on how I can get the related score data into my create view is appreciated.

Comment: I think I did mean SQL-Server as using database to save the data. Cannot find a way to edit the tags otherwise I would change it.

Comment: Easy, just click "edit tags".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'GolfScore.Models.ScoreViewModel' and 'GolfScore.Models.RoundViewModel'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

Is happening because you're using one to one relationship without specifying which end is the principal in the relationship.
Add a `[Required]` attribute on the attribute in which you're considering a principal in the relationship.

In your case I think it should be in the `ScoreViewModel` class. Which mean your class should be like this now:

```
public class ScoreViewModel
{
   [Key]
   public int ScoreId { get; set; }

   [Range(1 , 20)]
   public int ScoreTotal { get; set; }

   public int? HoleId { get; set; }
   public virtual HoleViewModel Hole { get; set; }

   public int? RoundId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public RoundViewModel Round { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that has appeared to solve the Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types error.

Comment: The remaining issues is now for me to work out how to post the data back to the database. there is no further error messages. So the rest of my code in the controller needs amending.